# table.column(0).checkboxes.selected() returns all rows of datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables, jquery-datatables-checkboxes

I'm new to datatables and have implemented checkbox's in each row of data table. I have followed [this sample](https://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/) for this.

I just want to return only selected row's data, but instead it returns all data on form submit action.

Here's screenshot

[image]

In screenshot above, I have only selected second and third row, but table.column(0).checkboxes.selected() returns all rows.

**Javascript Code**

```
  var paramedics;
    table;
    var i = 0;

    $(document).ready(function () {
       table = $("#example").DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/Home/GetCaseAllocations",
                "type": "GET",
                "datatype": "json",
             },
             "select": {
                "style": "multi"
            },
            "order": [[1, "asc"]],
            "columns": [
                {
                    "data": null,
                    'targets': 0,
                    'checkboxes': {                        
                        'selectRow': true
                    }
                },
                { "data": "patientId" },
                { "data": "name" },
                { "data": "age" },
                { "data": "zipCode" },
                { "data": "status" },
                { "data": "currentAllocation" },
                {
                    "data": "paramedicsAvailable", width: "200px",
                    render: function (data, type, row) {
                        var $select = $("<select></select>",
                            {
                                id: "allocation" + i
                            });
                        $.each(data, function (k, v) {
                            var $option = $("<option></option>",
                                {
                                    text: v,
                                    value: k
                                });
                            if (row.owner === v) {
                                $option.attr("selected", "selected")
                            }
                            $select.append($option);
                        });
                        return $select.prop("outerHTML");
                        i++;
                    }
                },
            ],
         });

        $("#frm-example").on('submit', function (e) {

            var form = this;

            var rows_selected = table.column(0).checkboxes.selected();

            // Iterate over all selected checkboxes
            $.each(rows_selected, function (index, rowId) {
                // Create a hidden element

                console.log(table.row(index));

                $(form).append(
                    $('<input>')
                        .attr('type', 'hidden')
                        .attr('name', 'id[]')
                        .val(rowId)
                );
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the current limitation of the jQuery DataTables Checkboxes plug-in is that column containing checkboxes must have unique data.

Use `columns.data` option to define data property in your response containing unique data. For example:

```
"columns": [
    {
        "data": "patientId",
        'targets': 0,
        'checkboxes': {                        
            'selectRow': true
        }
    },
    // ... skipped ...
],
```

Comment: this solve my problem, need the "data": "uniqe" to get the data

Answer (score 1):

Check the following

```js
// Get the selected
var row = $("#example").column(0).checkboxes.selected();
// Create variable for the ids array
var selected_items = [];
// Loop through to get the selected id
$.each(row, function(index, rowId){
   //this add selected ID as object into array
   selected_items.push({id:rowId});
});
```

Comment: i have already try this but its still showing column is not a function error